# SCADA like software to monitor running processes on my PC?

Tags: monitoring, monitor, scada

I will apologize in advance if this question is considered 'too broad', but I think it is a relevant question.

I enjoy writing programs that are designed to operate in a 'hands off manner'. And by that, I simply mean programs that monitor and respond to real-time data with no manual control from me (for the most part). However, I run into an issue where I have network issues or the program simply gets in a weird state and freezes. Besides the issues of program bugs and robustness, a real problem is I simply don't have a monitoring process to notify me when these programs freeze.

So my question:

Do there exist frameworks for monitoring real-time processes? I'm think something that can be hosted on a web server so that I can view my programs from any web capable device. Furthermore, this would be convenient to trend and monitor data I'm scraping from the web. I'm sure I could whip up something myself, but I'd imagine there is some type of frame work for fast/easy development of GUIs and offers plotting, graphs, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look to [eHorus](http://ehorus.com). Their beta program is being opened now and it's completely free!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is scada-lts, github: https://github.com/sdtabilit/Scada-LTS it's  open source and free, if you have any questions please contact me.